# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Downloading issue from bootable USB

Tags: devices

Recently I got a server machine I wanted to use for video game servers and I got Ubuntu server 18.04 bootable USB. It launched into the set up screen starting with language and keyboard. Then to interface, proxy server, and mirror address ,which i skipped for all. But when I get to step 7 out of 13 i get the following message: "Unfortunately probing for devices to install to failed. Please report a bug on Launchpad, and if possible include consents of the /var/log/installer directory". but when I looked at the files on the bootable USB i could not find what this var log was. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a very strange error indeed. Did you try to certify that your downloaded iso and written USB copied correctly? I.e. compare the md5, or just try reflashing the image to the USB. I've had similarly weird things happen from a bad flash or download.